# All locked up and nowhere to turn

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, story, calculation-puzzle

While working in your basement, you notice there is a portion of concrete which is not like the rest. It is funny you never noticed it before, but most of the time there was a rug covering it. Tapping on the area made a somewhat hollow sound, so hammer in hand, you smash into the concrete... Hands ringing, but hole made you see an object hidden under the concrete.

Getting a bigger hammer, you open up the hole more to allow for the object to be removed, and then pull out a small, but heavy trunk. There is a lock on it with 6 digit places and what appears to be the numbers 0-9 inclusive.

Inspecting the trunk, there is writing all over it. You notice 6 distinct strings of characters, but there is no indication of the order of the strings. These must have something to do with the contents, the combo, or both!

- zoxluycqpexgggbdthnwoxqkp
- ujzhpvklmrurndrdkmhrasklm
- ykswutxrjjluvrqvkljwdrhxx
- njjkjdwcciuentkstgcrthkws
- dmbequmdzgytgifbzgntphjtd
- mnwwhkjuqjijdoibrikevxntc

### Hint 1

> The characters within each string can be re-arranged and arrive at the same result...

After puzzling over this trunk and strings, you look at the lock a bit closer. Hardly noticeable under the grime is the inscription $27$, and on the other side is inscribed $10$. Once you clean up the lock as best you can, you also notice a faint inscription on the lock bar...
*Count the strings, you'll do just fine... make your math no greater than 9*. Strange indeed...

**What is the combination, *and* what is inside?** *(2 answers needed)*

Comment: Thank you for the tag update. I knew there had to be another one.

Comment: What do you mean by "piece together"?  Were the characters grouped together in some way, or are the groups completely random?

Comment: Updated puzzle to reflect the answer, and included a hint.

Comment: I would appreciate input as well as to the quality of this puzzle and what would make it better...

Answer (score 2):

My guess is:

> 665237

The clue "*Count the strings*" seems to indicate that the values of each character in each string should be summed.

> Using the ASCII values of each character, the strings have values {2763, 2742, 2827, 2716, 2706, 2725}, in their original order (this may satisfy the inscribed "$27$"). Using the alphabetical position of each character (i.e. a = 1, b = 2,...,z = 26), we have {363, 342, 427, 316, 306, 325}, respectively. Note that adding 2400 to each element in the second array yields the first array. Since there are 6 strings, it's reasonable to assume that each string corresponds to a single digit in the combination.

Now, the inscription indicates "*make your math no greater than 9*," which seems to suggest that...

> each value should be considered (mod 10), which would satisfy the inscribed $10$ and yield 6 digits between 0 and 9. Regardless of whether the ASCII values or alphabetical positions are used, the last digits of each string value are {3, 2, 7, 6, 6, 5}.

The problem mentions that "no indication of the order of the strings" which may suggest that we must introduce order to the strings ourselves.

> Thus, sorting the string values yields {2706, 2716, 2725, 2742, 2763, 2827} which translates to {6, 6, 5, 2, 3, 7}, or 665237. Another possible answer might be 235667, if sorting is performed after taking each value mod 10.

Comment: You are on the right path... keep it up! Your interpretation of 27 is not quite right, but you are getting there. I updated the last string, so do the math again on it. +1 for effort so far! Also, remember there are two answers I am looking for.

Comment: Instead of mod-ing it, try recursive adding of numerals in the resulting set until it's a single digit.

Answer (score 1):

As I am quitting Puzzling.SE, here is the answer.

First step:

> Convert each string from letters to numbers in the pattern a=1 as was said above.

Then:

> add them up as was done above by Joel Abraham. The totals are {363, 342, 427, 316, 306, 325}

Next:

> Fulfill the 27 by mod27 on the sums from above. You get {12, 18, 22, 19, 9, 5}

Next:

> Convert back to letters and then find the anagram. {L R V S I E} = {SILVER} = contents, which also points to the right order of the next step.

Finally:

> Take the previous sums and apply mod10 (make no larger than 9) to get the actual combo, just out of order. {3, 2, 7, 6, 6, 5} Re-arrange according to the order SILVER making {6, 6, 3, 7, 5, 2} which is the combination.

Final Answer is:

> The combination is 663752 and the contents are SILVER

Answer (score 0):

I might be crazy but a simple guess at the combo is

> 6789

for:

count the strings ->

```
zoxluycqpexgggbdthnwoxqkp
ujzhpvklmrurndrdkmhrasklm
ykswutxrjjluvrqvkljwdrhxx
njjkjdwcciuentkstgcrthkws
dmbequmdzgytgifbzgntphjtd
mnwwhkjuqjjjdoibrikevxntc
```

> is 6 (first digit)

and

> make your math no greater than 9 (last digit)

So,

> numbers 6-9 (6789) could be 4 digit combo.

Curious if conversion from base10 to baseN could be involved.

Comment: Don't give up! Remember, it is a 6 digit lock, so you will need more digits, and regarding conversion, there is one conversion which all the rest depend upon...

Answer (score 0):

I think someone else has already gotten closer, but I decided to go ahead and count up the instances of each letter in case it does any good.

**# of times each letter occurs**

```
1: af
3: oy
4: bepsvz
5: cilq
6: m
7: ghnwx
8: u
9: drt
11: jk
```

Comment: I would pay attention to the thinking of Joel Abraham... he is on the right track. Don't give up!